# Tonight's Stack Exchange Android app isn't rendering correctly, and crashes more often, on Lenovo 10" Yoga

Tags: bug, android-app

When viewing questions, regions of the screen paint over each other. And the app is falling on its face more often; I'll try to make sure you get trouble reports.

Removing/reinstalling didn't solve the rendering problem.

Comment: About incorrect rendering: dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260498/app-keeps-crashing-since-update-to-1-0-68-on-android-5-1-1-tablet (with screenshot)